# How to put my web site online

Tags: hosting, web

It's quite simple...I've developed a web site using symfony and wamp server on my pc and now I'd like to make it accessible to everyone on the web.

So what I'd like to know is the best host provider and domain register considering that it's a symfony project.

It's my first time launching a web site so I don't really know if I can have ssh access to the server host considering that it would be better than only dumping through ftp. Subversion is also important to quick updates.

Sorry for the noob question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Amazon's one year free Tier at http://aws.amazon.com/free/ if you really want to use ssh and svn. But that's probably too much for starters.

Take a look at this: http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/HostsSupportingSymfony

e.g. http://cloudcontrol.com/ gives you easy deployment and a free instance...

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. One question though...would there be a problem If I just use a regular hosting service and transfer the symfony project to the public_html page?

Comment: I never used symfony myself so I can't tell you for sure, but I would doubt that it works like that.